# Value of type 'Protocol' has no member 'Function'

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

In the code below, when I try to access `genericVar.someFunc()` I get the error

> "Value of type 'MyProtocol?' has no member 'someFunc'".

Being a generic variable, when I initialize the `MyOtherStruct` object, I will have to pass a concrete implementation of a `MyProtocol` conforming object, so why would I be getting this error?

```
public protocol MyProtocol {

    associatedtype T
    func someFunc() -> T
}

public struct myStruct: MyProtocol {
    public typealias T = Int16

    public func someFunc() -> Int16 {
        let myVar: Int16 = 7
        return myVar
    }
}

public struct myOtherStruct<MyProtocol> {

    var genericVar: MyProtocol?

    public init(localVal: MyProtocol?) {
        self.genericVar = localVal
        if genericVar != nil {
            var my = genericVar.someFunc()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generic type declaration is wrong. `MyProtocol` in the brackets is the name of the generic type parameter rather than the actual protocol. You need to declare another name for the generic type parameter and constrain it to `MyProtocol` like this: `struct MyOtherStruct<T:MyProtocol>`. Here `T` will be the generic type parameter of the struct and the `:MyProtocol` syntax enforces that `T` conform to `myProtocol`.

```
public struct MyOtherStruct<T:MyProtocol> {
    var genericVar: T?

    public init(localVal: T?) {
        self.genericVar = localVal
        if let genericVar = genericVar {
            let my = genericVar.someFunc()
        }
    }
}
```

Some other things to consider: you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is UpperCamelCase for types and when you want to access a property/method on an Optional value, instead of doing a `nil` comparison like `if genericVar != nil` you should use optional binding using `if let`.